# How to achieve the combobox with multiselect capability by typing

Tags: extjs5, extjs6

I am able to select the combobox with multiselect property as true..and i am able to select a value by typing but only one value..is there any way to select more than value by typing

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJs 6 `multiSelect` config from Combo box has been deperciated ..[This cfg has been DEPRECTED since 5.1.0](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-multiSelect)

Comment: Yes it is deprecated but we can still use the multiselect and i am able to select the mouse and i want to select multiple ones by typing the values.And also the tagfield is not fit in my scenario. .thats why i am trying to use combo with multiselect